# Android generate Views with no parent

Tags: android, kotlin, view

Still pretty new to Android I've successfully assembled an ImageView - located in my activity XML - to create a video, for testing purpose. 
Now I want to create many Views programatically, without having them attached to an XML activity, or a parent, and possibly later in a separate thread.

I'm trying to that in the following fashion:

```
    val testView = View(requireContext())
    testView.setBackgroundColor(requireContext().getColor(R.color.blue))
    testView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(480, 480)
```

But it looks like my view dimensions are 0:0 and my video assembler crashes. 
How to properly create my views?

Thanks!

Comment: The view gets its dimensions from its parent. The layout params describe the size the view wants to be. The parent uses that and sets a size on the view. So any View that is not yet part of a layout that has been validated will not have a size yet. Also, you need to be using DIP units rather than hard-coding pixel sizes. So `480` should be `480f / context.resouces.displayMetrics.density`.

Comment: I later convert the View into a Bitmap to finally get a ByteArray. Should I directly use a Canvas instead of a View?

Comment: I guess it depends on what exactly you're doing. You can force a view to a specific size by calling `view.layout(0, 0, width, height)`. As an aside, you mentioned creating "many" Views, and now you're saying you are converting them to Bitmap images. [You'll need to be very careful about memory management if you have many images.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics)

Comment: My video builder requires ByteArrays, so my source can be pretty much anything. My go-to solution would be to create Views as I believe it's easier, but I still need to convert them to Bitmap to create a ByteArray, so as I struggle to find a solution I was wondering why not draw directly in a Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

How did you check that view dimensions are 0:0 if it's not in view hierarchy?

**Using your code:**

```
val testView = View(this)
testView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
testView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(480, 480)
```

And just adding it to the content

```
findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.content).addView(testView)
```

Displays the square with background with size 480x480

Even if you debug
[image: textView value]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the asker has already figured it out, but for reference, the solution is this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var testView: View

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testView = View(this)
        testView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        val size = (480 * resources.displayMetrics.density).roundToInt()

        // Assign dimensions and position to view.
        testView.layout(0, 0, size, size)

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

        // Render to canvas
        testView.draw(canvas)

        // Copy
        val targetView = findViewById<View>(R.id.target)
        val drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
        targetView.background = drawable
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]